# How do I inject new request header with json data in proxy request flow?

Tags: apigee

I am trying to inject a new request header in the proxy request flow using JS policy to be sent to the backend server. When I look at the debug trace, I see that the json data in the request header is distorted.

I am trying to inject some string like

```
{"scope":"","time_till":2264,"id_1":"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM","custom_data":{"c_id":"test_data"}}
```

But when I look at the trace window I see this

```
{"scope":"","time_till":2264,id_1":"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM,"custom_data":{"c_id":"test_data"}}
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
var obj = {"scope":"","time_till":2264,"id_1":"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM","custom_data":{"c_id":"test_data"}};
var header_str = JSON.stringify(obj);
context.setVariable('json-header',header_str);
request.headers['x-json-hedar']= header_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems to work.  Here's an example response where I set the header string as a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Accept: */*
x-json-header: {"scope":"","time_till":2264,"id_1":"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM","custom_data":{"c_id":"test_data"}}
Content-Length: 0
```

It appears this is only an issue with the Apigee debug session / trace tool as the header value was set correctly.  Here was the JSON download of the debug session showing this header value:

```
{
    "name": "x-json-header",
    "value": "{\"scope\":\"\",\"time_till\":2264,id_1\":\"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM,\"custom_data\":{\"c_id\":\"test_data\"}}"
}
```

You can see that the value passed to the UI for displaying the debug info has the malformed json:

`id_1\":\"hUXLXVqpA1J4vA9sayk2UttWNdM,`

Comment: Thank you. I will check my back end servers to see if the values are being received as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a problem with the Apigee debug/trace UI. I see the malformed JSON trickle down to my backend service.

Here is the header I'm trying to send -

```
{"timeStamp":"2349218349381274","latitude":"34.589","longitude":"-37.343","clientIp":"127.0.0.0","deviceId":"MOBILE_TEST_DEVICE_AGAIN","macAddress":"23:45:345:345","deviceType":"phone","deviceOS":"iOS","deviceModel":"iPhone 5S","connection":"5G","carrier":"Vodafone","refererURL":"http://www.google.com","xforwardedFor":"129.0.0.0","sessionId":"kfkls498327ksdjf","application":"mobile-app","appVersion":"7.6.5","serviceVersion":"1.0","userAgent":"Gecko"}
```

But Apigee reads the header as below. Note the missing start quotes from some fields.

```
{"timeStamp":"2349218349381274",latitude":"34.589,longitude":"-37.343,clientIp":"127.0.0.0,deviceId":"MOBILE_TEST_DEVICE_AGAIN,macAddress":"23:45:345:345,deviceType":"phone,deviceOS":"iOS,deviceModel":"iPhone 5S,connection":"5G,carrier":"Vodafone,refererURL":"http://www.google.com,xforwardedFor":"129.0.0.0,sessionId":"kfkls498327ksdjf,application":"mobile-app,appVersion":"7.6.5,serviceVersion":"1.0,"userAgent":"Gecko"}
```

The header is used in a service callout to a backend service which parses it. And rightly so, I get the below error -

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)):      was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@22549cdc; line: 1, column: 35]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1378)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:599)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleUnusualFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1275)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parseFieldName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:611)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:301)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2796)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1942)
```

Comment: I am seeing a different behavior though, I am seeing that all the headers are getting passed as the request body. Its weird.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter strange behaviour when adding JSON to a context variable for example like the following:

```
 var header_str = JSON.stringify(obj);
 context.setVariable('json-header',header_str);
```

I appreciate this is an example so you may not have included the full extent of the problem but this normally works (now it is not added to a variable first):

```
request.headers['x-json-header'] = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Code like this also works if you can send the request from JavaScript

```
var headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Language": "en"};
var sessionRequest = new Request(url, 'POST', headers, body);
var exchange = httpClient.send(sessionRequest);
exchange.waitForComplete()
if (exchange.isSuccess()){
    var responseObj = exchange.getResponse().content.asJSON;
    if (responseObj.error){
        request.content += JSON.stringify(responseObj);
    }
}
```

Also, I have had success with using an AssignMessage policy to build a request, followed by a Callout policy to read the stored request and then make that request and store the result in a response object which can then be read by an Extract Variables policy.